# Is a Uniform Resource Locator and a Universal Resource Locator the same thing?

Tags: url, resources, uniform

Working with this, are they technically the same thing, or different? If different, how so?

Comment: That means its a correct answer is universal recource locater Am i right dear ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In computing, a uniform resource identifier (URI) is a string of
>   characters used to identify a name or a web resource

VS

> A uniform resource locator, abbreviated URL, also known as web
>   address, is a specific character string that constitutes a reference
>   to a resource.

Never heard about `UNIVERSAL` but here are the common, URL and URI, I guess Universal must be probably a synonym

This guy [here](http://www.cefls.org/esenior_2_3_understanding_url.htm) uses Universal in his article

Comment: The original question was more to do with Universal vs. Uniform, not URL vs. URI, I think.

Comment: @tristan2468 Just realized

Comment: @Mr.Alien I had a problem where a question was marked wrong, and was told there was no such thing as a "uniform" resource locator, and that "universal" was right. Was almost 99% sure that I was correct. Thanks for your guy's help.

Comment: @LoganDeyo Uniform is correct, never read universal anywhere :) you welcome

Comment: @Mr.Alien Exactly what I thought! Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

It is confusing and I just researched the topic. There is confusion in the naming. In the beginning RFC's the URI Universal Resource Identifier was born with Uniform Resource Locator (URL) from w3.org many people confused the terms and old dogs like me still call them Universal Resource Locator. Although the correct terminology is; Uniform for everything.
URI URL and URN are: Uniform Resource (Identifier, Locator and Name)

Answer (score 1):

This might be an old question but they are the same. If you have never heard of Universal Resource Locator then you are probably pretty young and don't remember the dial up days, that's understandable. It was Universal before it was ever called Resource. Neither is wrong.

Comment: The man who invented it wanted to call it the Universal Resource Locater, but someone else said that it would be egotistical or something along those lines to call it "Universal," so they changed the name to Uniform Resource Locater.  It became Ubiquitous, but it still kept the name Uniform Resource Locater.

Answer (score 0):

The correct term is Uniform Resource Locator:
Ref:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator